# Unwanted background on an div animation before the page finish loading

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I spent a few hours and couldn't find a fix

On this site https://2sync.com
I have the text animation is getting a weird blue background that disappears after the page is loaded.

Here's a GIF:

[image: Demo of the unwanted background]

I'm getting this on Arc browser: Version 1.30.0 (46409)
Chromium Engine Version 121.0.6167.184

This happens only on the production site, and couldn't replicate it on the dev environment. When I remove the animation, it's fixed (but I still want the animation)/

FYI, here's the SCSS code I'm using:

```scss
  .scrolling-words-box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3rem;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    transform: translateY(10px);

    ul {
      padding: 0;
      animation: text-scroll-up 8s infinite;

      li {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        height: 3rem;
        list-style: none;
      }
    }
  }

  // Variables
  $item-count: 4;

  @keyframes text-scroll-up {
    @for $i from 1 through ($item-count - 1) {
      #{($i * 25) - 10%}, #{$i * 25%} {
        transform: translateY(((-100% / $item-count) * $i));
      }
    }
  }
```

With the following HTML

```html
<div class="scrolling-words-box">
    <div class="scrolling-words-content">
      <ul>
        <li style="color: #ea4335;">
          Todoist
        </li>
        <li style="color: #4285f4;">
          Calendar
        </li>
        <li style="color: #34a853;">
          Emails
        </li>
        <li style="color: #fbbc04;">
          Contacts
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have tried to set `background-color:transparent` at the `li` or `ul`?  Perhaps with an `!important`.

Comment: I may be way off base here but have you tried a Band-Aid like converting the SCSS to CSS? It works for me but might not in your case.

Comment: @JimDandyBOA SCSS gets compiled to CSS. There's nothing to fix there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your current working site and found that some CSS is update after loading the page.

The background color that appears on the whole text is the background color of `soon` label, which you have applied. It appears because the parent can't find `position: relative;` css before the complete load page. So add/update below css

```
.scrolling-words-box ul li .v-chip {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this has resolved the issue. It was indeed due to the v-chip not being rendered properly.